# FILE uploading PHP mysql in server

Tags: php, mysql, upload

I am trying to upload file by PHP mySQL.My script is perfectly working on localhost but in the server it is not working. It is not uploading file into server. Here is my action script.

```
//This is the directory where images will be saved 
$target1 = "notice/";
$target2 = "notice/"; 
$target3 = "notice/"; 
$target4 = "notice/";  

$target1 = $target1 . basename( $_FILES['photo1']['name']); 
$target2 = $target2 . basename( $_FILES['photo2']['name']);
$target3 = $target3 . basename( $_FILES['photo3']['name']);
$target4 = $target4 . basename( $_FILES['photo4']['name']);

 //This gets all the other information from the form 
$day=$_POST['day']; 
$month=$_POST['month']; 
$year=$_POST['year']; 
$title=$_POST['title'];
$dis=$_POST['dis'];
$pic1=($_FILES['photo1']['name']);
$pic2=($_FILES['photo2']['name']); 
$pic3=($_FILES['photo3']['name']); 
$pic4=($_FILES['photo4']['name']);  

// Connects to your Database 
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
mysql_select_db("trustcol") or die(mysql_error()) ; 

//Writes the information to the database 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO notice VALUES (NULL, '$day', '$month', '$year', '$title',          '$dis', '$pic1', '$pic2', '$pic3', '$pic4')") ; 

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo1']['tmp_name'], $target1);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo2']['tmp_name'], $target2);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo3']['tmp_name'], $target3);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo4']['tmp_name'], $target4);
include('adminbanner.php'); 
include('adminmenu2.php');
?>
```

this is working on my PC/localhost perfectly but in the server it is not uploading files why?

Comment: Have you checked target folder permissions? It should be 777.

Comment: permission, path, max uploaded file, etc..

Answer (score 2):

1. Do you have file_uploads enabled in your php.ini (or using ini_set)?
2. Is the filesize larger than the [upload_max_filesize](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) configuration option in php.ini?
3. Look into these others, too: PHP.ini

   [max_input_time](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php),
   [memory_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit),
   [max_execution_time](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time), and
   [post_max_size](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)
4. Look for permission on the upload folder

Answer (score 0):

Did this work in a terminal but not through HTML?  If so I had a similar problem.  I kept staring at my php, but it turned out I had an issue with my form html.  I forgot to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to my `<form>` tag to accomodate file uploads.